# How to change link Navbar color while scrolling in React or Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

While scrolling, I want to change the color Links depending on Id. how can i do that?

Example:

```
     <div>
          <nav>
            <div className="bg-mainColor h-16 flex justify-between">
              <div className="text-white">Navbar</div>

              <div>
                <Link to="/" className="text-white">
                  Home
                </Link>
                <Link to="#first" className="text-white">
                  Features
                </Link>
                <a href="#" className="text-white">
                  Courses
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>

          <div className="min-h-screen" id="feature">
            Features
          </div>

          <div className="min-h-screen" id="course">
            Courses
          </div>

        </div>
```

Check this picture to understand me more 
[image: Demo Navbar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must add an Id to your link and add an event listener on your componentDidMount :

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll' , this.handleScroll)
}
```

and your `handleScroll` is like :

```
handleScroll  = (event) => {
  //handle your event base on scroll in pixels or what ever for example : 
  if(window.scrollY > 100) {
     let aEl = document.getElementById('YOUR_LINK_ID');
     aEl.setAttribute("style" , "color : red")

  } 
}
```

and dont forget to `removeEventListener` on `ComponentWillUnMount` :

```
componentWillUnMount() {
  document.removeEventListener('scroll',this.handleScroll);
}
```