# where to place componentDidMount in order to change link Navbar color while scrolling in React / Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235809/how-to-change-link-navbar-color-while-scrolling-in-react-or-gatsby) and I understand that I need to add an id to my navbar link and add an event listener on componentDidMount (with the handleScroll function), this is clear to me already.

I will apologize beforehand because I might be asking something stupid or something I was supposed to know already.

The issue is, even though I am experienced with vanilla JS, I am pretty new to react and gatsby so I am not sure exactly where to place componentDidMount at the [gatsby starter I am using](https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-starter-portfolio-cara).

This starter is a single page app, all the sections are loaded in the index (home page). One of these sections for instance is named About and I would like to add componentDidMount in there. I have shadowed the about.tsx file to the components directory but I am not sure where to place componentDidMount.

about.tsx content:

```js
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from "theme-ui"
import Divider from "../elements/divider"
import Inner from "../elements/inner"
import Content from "../elements/content"
import SVG from "./svg"
import { UpDown, UpDownWide } from "../styles/animations"
// @ts-ignore
import AboutMDX from "../sections/about"


const About = ({ offset, factor = .99 }: { offset: number; factor?: number }) => (
  <div>
    <Divider
      bg="divider"
      clipPath="polygon(0 16%, 100% 4%, 100% 82%, 0 94%)"
      speed={0.2}
      offset={offset}
      factor={factor}
    />
    <Divider speed={0.1} offset={offset} factor={factor}>
      <UpDown>
        <SVG icon="box" hiddenMobile width={6} color="icon_blue" left="50%" top="75%" />
        <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="70%" top="20%" />
        <SVG icon="triangle" width={8} stroke color="icon_darkest" left="25%" top="5%" />
        <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={24} color="icon_orange" left="80%" top="80%" />
      </UpDown>
      <UpDownWide>
        <SVG icon="arrowUp" hiddenMobile width={16} color="icon_purple" left="5%" top="80%" />
        <SVG icon="triangle" width={12} stroke color="icon_brightest" left="95%" top="50%" />
        <SVG icon="circle" hiddenMobile width={6} color="icon_brightest" left="85%" top="15%" />
        <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="45%" top="10%" />
      </UpDownWide>
      <SVG icon="circle" hiddenMobile width={6} color="icon_brightest" left="4%" top="20%" />
      <SVG icon="circle" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="70%" top="60%" />
      <SVG icon="box" width={6} color="icon_orange" left="10%" top="10%" />
      <SVG icon="box" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="20%" top="30%" />
      <SVG icon="hexa" width={8} stroke color="icon_darkest" left="80%" top="70%" />
    </Divider>
    <Content speed={0.4} offset={offset} factor={factor}>
      <Inner>
        <AboutMDX/>
      </Inner>
    </Content>
  </div>
)

export default About
```

I appreciate if someone could point me out how can I add componentDidMount to this about section? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: From what I could gather, this is a stateless functional component (right?) and such won't support lifecycles methods. But I can't for the sake of it figure out how do I convert this component to a stateful component or how do I wrap it in a stateful container.

Comment: Functional components can use state and manage change effects using Hooks. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: Now I am confused, I thought functional components (aka stateless components) did not support state and effects. And thought class components (aka stateful components) did. Anyways, I can't figure out how to convert this stateless component to a stateful component so I can use componentDidMount.

Comment: They introduced Hooks because it improves developer experience, and function components typically perform better than class/prototype based ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a functional component there where doesn't handle a pure `state` as you may know (you don't need a constructor, etc. I will add some docs at the end of the answer). You have exactly the same functionality because of React hooks.

In your case, you won't be able to have a `componentDidMount()` *per se* because of the previously mentioned, however, you have a [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook that adds exactly the same functionality.

```
const About = ({ offset, factor = .99 }: { offset: number; factor?: number }) => {
 
  useEffect(() => {
    // your function that handles the scroll
  },[]);

  return <div>
    <Divider
      bg="divider"
      clipPath="polygon(0 16%, 100% 4%, 100% 82%, 0 94%)"
      speed={0.2}
      offset={offset}
      factor={factor}
    />
    <Divider speed={0.1} offset={offset} factor={factor}>
      <UpDown>
        <SVG icon="box" hiddenMobile width={6} color="icon_blue" left="50%" top="75%" />
        <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="70%" top="20%" />
        <SVG icon="triangle" width={8} stroke color="icon_darkest" left="25%" top="5%" />
        <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={24} color="icon_orange" left="80%" top="80%" />
      </UpDown>
      <UpDownWide>
        <SVG icon="arrowUp" hiddenMobile width={16} color="icon_purple" left="5%" top="80%" />
        <SVG icon="triangle" width={12} stroke color="icon_brightest" left="95%" top="50%" />
        <SVG icon="circle" hiddenMobile width={6} color="icon_brightest" left="85%" top="15%" />
        <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="45%" top="10%" />
      </UpDownWide>
      <SVG icon="circle" hiddenMobile width={6} color="icon_brightest" left="4%" top="20%" />
      <SVG icon="circle" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="70%" top="60%" />
      <SVG icon="box" width={6} color="icon_orange" left="10%" top="10%" />
      <SVG icon="box" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="20%" top="30%" />
      <SVG icon="hexa" width={8} stroke color="icon_darkest" left="80%" top="70%" />
    </Divider>
    <Content speed={0.4} offset={offset} factor={factor}>
      <Inner>
        <AboutMDX/>
      </Inner>
    </Content>
  </div>
}

export default About
```

The `useEffect`, basically is kind of combination of `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`. As you can see, it accepts an array as a parameter called deps (dependencies). It means that you can pass a variable (or an array of variables, like `props`) there to trigger the effect (`useEffect`) function. If you pass an empty array, it will behave as a `componentDidMount`, triggering the function once the DOM tree is loaded.

Keep in mind that handling a scroll in Gatsby may be tricky since `gatsby develop` is rendered in the browser-side (where there's a `window` object) but `gatsby build` occurs in the server-side (Node side), where for obvious reasons [there's no `window` or `document`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/). You may need to add a condition to bypass it:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
       // your function that handles the scroll
    }
  },[]);
```

I would recommend some readings:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html
- https://medium.com/wesionary-team/react-functional-components-vs-class-components-86a2d2821a22
- [https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-choose-functional-components#:~:text=Rendering%20JSX,which%20has%20a%20render%20method](https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-choose-functional-components#:%7E:text=Rendering%20JSX,which%20has%20a%20render%20method).
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/

Comment: Thanks Ferran, I am trying to use your suggestion but I think its missing a parenthesis in there, am I  correct?

I am getting a ')' expected.

And If I do add the missing ) I get this error:

> 25 |   return <div>
     |   ^

Comment: It looks fine to me. There's a curly brace at the end of the statement, not a `)`

Comment: Ferran, your answer is correct and works. You were right, I missed the curly brackets. I am not sure what to do here since Oussama's answer is also correct. I cant upvote your answer because of my lack of reputation :( Oussama's answers the question on the title "where to place componentDidMount" but your answer taught me I did not need to use componentDidMount. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: You started with a functional component and my answer was focused on teaching why you were wrong, what to do, and how to do it, providing and searching articles that I thought that you may find it useful, with your starting use-case (in addition I answered faster hehe). I can't talk about the other answer but it changes your component (to a class component) to add a `componentDidMount`. Obviously, the choice is yours, it's up to you. The functional component has better performance than the class-based ones. Despite the upvotes, I'm always happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

A Gatsby app is still a react app so everything you learned in react is still available in Gatsby.
A lot of people think that Gatsby is just for creating page websites but it's capable of a lot more than that.
For your question a snippet is worth a thousand words so here's your solution:

```js
/** @jsx jsx */
import React, {Component} from "react"
import { jsx } from "theme-ui"
import Divider from "../elements/divider"
import Inner from "../elements/inner"
import Content from "../elements/content"
import SVG from "./svg"
import { UpDown, UpDownWide } from "../styles/animations"
// @ts-ignore
import AboutMDX from "../sections/about"


type AboutProps = { offset: number; factor?: number }
export default class About extends Component <AboutProps, {}> {
  
  componentDidMoun(){
    // do whatever you want here
  }
  render(){
    const { offset, factor = .99 } = this.props;
    return(
      <div>
        <Divider
          bg="divider"
          clipPath="polygon(0 16%, 100% 4%, 100% 82%, 0 94%)"
          speed={0.2}
          offset={offset}
          factor={factor}
        />
        <Divider speed={0.1} offset={offset} factor={factor}>
          <UpDown>
            <SVG icon="box" hiddenMobile width={6} color="icon_blue" left="50%" top="75%" />
            <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="70%" top="20%" />
            <SVG icon="triangle" width={8} stroke color="icon_darkest" left="25%" top="5%" />
            <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={24} color="icon_orange" left="80%" top="80%" />
          </UpDown>
          <UpDownWide>
            <SVG icon="arrowUp" hiddenMobile width={16} color="icon_purple" left="5%" top="80%" />
            <SVG icon="triangle" width={12} stroke color="icon_brightest" left="95%" top="50%" />
            <SVG icon="circle" hiddenMobile width={6} color="icon_brightest" left="85%" top="15%" />
            <SVG icon="upDown" hiddenMobile width={8} color="icon_darkest" left="45%" top="10%" />
          </UpDownWide>
          <SVG icon="circle" hiddenMobile width={6} color="icon_brightest" left="4%" top="20%" />
          <SVG icon="circle" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="70%" top="60%" />
          <SVG icon="box" width={6} color="icon_orange" left="10%" top="10%" />
          <SVG icon="box" width={12} color="icon_darkest" left="20%" top="30%" />
          <SVG icon="hexa" width={8} stroke color="icon_darkest" left="80%" top="70%" />
        </Divider>
        <Content speed={0.4} offset={offset} factor={factor}>
          <Inner>
            <AboutMDX/>
          </Inner>
        </Content>
      </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer should also be accepted because it answers the question in the title. Oussama I appreciate your time and teaching me how to convert the component, thank you very much, I am accepting the other answer though because Ferran answered first was able to show me why I didnt need to convert the component and why. Your answer is still correct and should also be accepted. Unfortunately I dont have enough reputation to upvote your answer, I apologize and once again thank you for your answer and for your time.